# Joomla - htaccess Redirects Error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I've had a Joomla 2.5.28 site for quite a while now and recently changed hosting providers. On the new server I managed to get Joomla updated to 3.2.7 and get it to run normally.

Now for the tricky part:
On my previous hoster I had a second installation being kind of the gateway to the other site. It just lets you select language and that's it.

My domain is www.cyclingtoserve.at with Joomla Main being /joomla and Joomla portal being /3.1

I figured by adding a REDIRECT rule from / to /3.1 I could get the portal up and running again. Sadly not.

This is what I get:

[image: I did a bad]

I thought I could undo this by deleting the .htaccess file. The problem lives on though.

I've tried just about everything. Help is VERY MUCH appreciated!

**Edit01:** A bit more info may be interesting.
The Joomla install is in /joomla while the other page is in /3.1
The .htaccess file however was in the root directory.

**Edit02:** I have managed to remove the wrong redirection. Question is: What is the correct way to redirect people from www.cyclingtoserve.at to /3.1? (without it showing up in the address)

**Edit03:** Here is a graphical representation (FTP) of the folder structure.
[ftp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPsvq.png)

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using in your htaccess?  You need to match better so it knows to not redirect if URL already has the /3.1/ in it.

Comment: well as mentioned before, I currently have no .htaccess file. I could use the default that came with Joomla, (htaccess.txt) but same result.

Comment: Where is the redirect you setup then?  in the cPanel redirect tool?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. I'm used to working with WordPress, but not with Joomla.
I used a .htaccess file to set it up, I don't know where it got saved to, but after deleting the .htaccess file the error persists. So it has to have been saved somewhere.

Comment: Go to your hosting's cPanel or equivalent and look for a redirect tool there.  I ran into that once where I was pulling my hair out looking through FTP and the redirect was in cPanel

Comment: Ok I have managed to get rid of the wrong redirection (for some reason Ctrl + F5 did not clear my browser cache).
The question that remains, is: How do I redirect root to folder /3.1 correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I've had to give up using .htaccess for the redirection.
I would have loved the recommended way (and still would like to know how).

Solution:
index.html in root has the following lines:

```
<frameset rows="100%" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://cyclingtoserve.at/3.1/" name="Content" noresize>
<noframes>
```

It may be the quick and dirty way of dealing with this issue, but it works.

If you can reproduce the same results with .htaccess, I'd love to tag it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the redirect loop, you need to first check to see if your are already in the /3.1/ folder.  Try this:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/3.1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/3.1/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't change a thing. Still gets me to the main joomla, not the portal. From what I understand "if request_url is not /3.1 goto %url%/3.1", correct?

Comment: I think I am confused.  Are you saying that /3.1/ is NOT a subfolder within your http://www.cyclingtoserve.at site, but rather on the same hierarchical level within your hosting?

Comment: Let me rephrase that.
Root. There are two essential folders: the /3.1 folder and the /joomla folder. In root there is an index.html. root is supposed to redirect to /3.1 and after a choice /3.1 redirects to /joomla

Unnecessary complicated, I know. But I wasn't the one who originally designed the site.